# Absolute integral closure of Noetherian local domain

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local domain, let $K(R)$ be the total fraction field of $R$ and let $R^{+}$ be the absolute integral closure of $R$. Consider the $R^{+}$-module $K(R)\otimes_{R} R^{+}$ via  extension of scalars. Let $J$ be the ideal $\mathfrak{m}R^{+}$ of $R^{+}$. I don't know if $J(K(R)\otimes_{R} R^{+})=K(R)\otimes_{R} R^{+}$.

Comment: What is  the absolute integral closure?

Comment: Is the integral closure in the algebraic closure of the field K(R).

Comment: Isn't $K(R)\otimes_RR^+$ simply the algebraic closure of $K(R)$? It being a field then trivially implies the equality you ask about.

Comment: I don't believe that $K(R)\otimes_{R}R^{+}$ be a field. $R^{+}$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}R^{+}$.

Comment: If $f \in R^+$, then from an integral eqn $f^s + \sum_ja_jf^{s-j} = 0$ of $f$ over $R$, you have $f(f^{s-1}+a_{s-1}f^{s-2}+\cdots+a_1) = -a_0$, which is a unit in $K(R) \otimes_R R^+$

Comment: $K(R)\otimes_R R^+$ is the localization of $R^+$ at nonzero elements of $R$. Any element of the algebraic closure has an $R$-multiple in $R^+$ by "clearing denominators" from its minimal polynomial, so will lie in that localization.

Comment: An integral integral-domain extension of a field is a field.  To see this, note your tensor product (call it $T$) is an integral domain since it is a localization of $R^+$.  $T$ also is an integral extension of $K(R)$.  Hence all primes of $T$ lie over $(0)$ and by incomparability, they are all minimal (see going up).  Thus $(0)$ is the only prime (since it's obviously the smallest) and you have a field.

Comment: @CARLO It's not true that $R^+$ is local, nor that $mR^+$ is the maximal ideal of $R^+$. Take for instance $R$ to be the localization $\Bbb Z_{(2)}$. Its maximal ideals correspond to ideals lying over $2$ in $\overline{\Bbb Z}$, of which there are uncountably many.

Comment: If $R$ is complete local then $R^+$ is still local.  Indeed, $R^+$ is local if and only if $R$ is Henselian (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04GE)